# Angular 2 - Building / Deploying on SystemJS Base? (RC.5)

Tags: angular, build, webpack, systemjs, jspm

I have a series of questions and some assumptions I'd like to challenge.  I am having trouble understanding the build step of Angular 2.  I have a completed Angular 2 project that is built with NPM and SystemJS. The project runs fine with either lite-server or webpack-dev-server. I have attempted to use WebPack, but can't figure it out, the build is missing files.  I am using bootstrap, jquery, angular materiel font/icons, and a few other 3rd party libs that I have installed with NPM(referened in my index.html).

I have seen a lot of links to similar questions where people have seed projects, but they don't seem to really explain how its all working.  When I hit errors, I'm not sure how to proceed.

---

### Assumptions:

1. SystemJS is a module loader
2. Webpack, when configured correctly, will build the project including all necessary files (html,css,js,etc) in a dist folder. (this feels like one of my issues: maybe webpack just builds the node_modules into a single js file?)
3. Projects that begin with a systemJS base are easier to build with tools like JSPM instead of ones like Webpack

### Questions:

1. Should I ditch webpack and attempt to use JSPM since I'm using SystemJS?  I have never used gulp or jpsm so both would require some kind of tutorial/docs.
2. Is there a way to use webpack to build my app that I am missing somehow?  If someone could provide step by step instructions?  I have the config files, I have the loaders, I have my polyfills.ts and vendor.ts(with bootstrap/jquery) files.

---

### File Tree

```
Folder PATH
|   index.html
|   karma.conf.js
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   systemjs.config.js
|   tree.txt
|   tsconfig.json
|   typings.json
|   webpack.config.js
|   
+---app
|   |   app.component.css
|   |   app.component.html
|   |   app.component.js
|   |   app.component.js.map
|   |   app.component.ts
|   |   app.module.js
|   |   app.module.js.map
|   |   app.module.ts
|   |   app.routing.js
|   |   app.routing.js.map
|   |   app.routing.ts
|   |   http.service.js
|   |   http.service.js.map
|   |   http.service.ts
|   |   main.js
|   |   main.js.map
|   |   main.ts
|   |   
|   +---compare
|   |       compare.component.css
|   |       compare.component.html
|   |       compare.component.js
|   |       compare.component.js.map
|   |       compare.component.ts
|   |       
|   +---home
|   |       home.component.css
|   |       home.component.html
|   |       home.component.js
|   |       home.component.js.map
|   |       home.component.ts
|   |       
|   +---img
|   |       h_logo.png
|   |       
|   +---pipes
|   |       filter-data-pipe.js
|   |       filter-data-pipe.js.map
|   |       filter-data-pipe.ts
|   |       format-metric-pipe.js
|   |       format-metric-pipe.js.map
|   |       format-metric-pipe.ts
|   |       number-to-symbol.js
|   |       number-to-symbol.js.map
|   |       number-to-symbol.ts
|   |       unique-values-pipe.js
|   |       unique-values-pipe.js.map
|   |       unique-values-pipe.ts
|   |       
|   +---printer
|   |       printer.component.css
|   |       printer.component.html
|   |       printer.component.js
|   |       printer.component.js.map
|   |       printer.component.ts
|   |       
|   +---scoreboard
|   |       scoreboard.component.css
|   |       scoreboard.component.html
|   |       scoreboard.component.js
|   |       scoreboard.component.js.map
|   |       scoreboard.component.ts
|   |       
|   \---topnav
|           topnav.component.css
|           topnav.component.html
|           topnav.component.js
|           topnav.component.js.map
|           topnav.component.ts
|                        
+---config
|       helpers.js
|       karma-test-shim.js
|       karma.conf.js
|       polyfills.ts
|       vendor.ts
|       webpack.common.js
|       webpack.dev.js
|       webpack.prod.js
|       webpack.test.js
|            
+---node_modules
```

---

### webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './config/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './config/vendor.ts',
    'app': './app/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif||woff|ico)$/, loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.css$/, exclude: helpers.root('app'), loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap') },
      { test: /\.css$/, include: helpers.root('app'), loader: 'raw' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass'] },
      { test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000' },
      { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // template: './index.html'
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

---

### webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

---

### pollyfills.js

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

import 'ts-helpers';

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
  // Production
} else {
  // Development
  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

### vendor.js

```
// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs'

//Extras
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,400italic,300italic,600italic';


// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...
```

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>myApp</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Provided Assets -->
    <!-- Material Design Icons by Google see information here: http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/ --> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,400italic,300italic,600italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DatePicker -->
    <link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body> 
     <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [read this](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/07/jspm-vs-webpack/)

Comment: This article is great, but doesn't really address my issue.  I am at point A and I need to get to point C.  Point B is some kind of bundler (sounds like JSPM works better with systemjs), but I'm only using that b/c it was in my angular 2 template I used. If systemJS can be converted and webpack make more sense that's fine.  I just not sure how to proceed.